# Determine Surface TypeCover 2 Firmware Version

Tags: keyboard, firmware, microsoft-surface-pro

I have found various references to [Surface TypeCover 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FG7MMDK) firmware versions.

[This is an example](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/install-update-activate/2-update-history):

> Surface Type Cover 2 Firmware Update Device (v2.0.517.0) update improves multiple finger support on the touchpad.

How do I determine what version of firmware my Type Cover 2 has?

Answer (score 1):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/1yvkpt/how_can_i_tell_which_firmware_version_i_am_running/) provides a clue that

> The firmware devices are listed under firmware, and keyboards for the touch/type cover "firmwares". Their versions can be found by right clicking each respective object and going to the driver tab.

That thread, however, is incorrect for finding Type Cover 2 firmware.  The correct device to look for seems to be called *Surface Type Cover 2 Firmware Update Device* not *Surface Touch Cover Filter Device*.  The full path to that device is as follows:

```
Device Manager
 |
 + Human Interface Devices
    |
    + Surface Type Cover 2 Firmware Update Device
```

[image]

Once you find that device, you right-click it to discover the driver version.  As best I can tell, the driver version *is* the firmware version.

[image]